# Git with Visual Studio 2015 not allowing my partner to create a new project

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-2015

Git, used with VS 2015, as the title indicates, is having issues; we're creating a large application that so far has 16 projects for separation of concerns.

The majority of the time, git is fine, although sometimes it does untrack things we don't want it to. Probably, it's just because we're so busy doing things, we don't realize sometimes that new files aren't always tracked by Git by default. Whatever.

But now, my partner has created a new project for our API services, and it untracks the project and class files; but when he adds them back into the commit and commits the entire thing, it will either not let him commit, or it will say it's committed, and then I cannot get it from syncing with him. It's like Git just doesn't want the project to exist.

I can upload projects just fine. I uploaded a new project and added references to a couple of our other projects, and committed, and everything worked fine when he sync'd up. But for some reason, he can't create this one project. We're not sure why.

And, we can't seem to access the command prompt on his machine because he has a separate drive for his data, he stores everything on his D: drive. Command prompt will not access his D: drive for some reason. We can probably look up that issue and figure it out quickly, if we need to use command prompt with Git to fix this issue. But we're simply wondering why Git is doing this and what we can do to fix it. We have researched it and found nothing.

The only proposed solution was using the command prompt with Git to use `git add -u` and add the files manually, but we'd need to add the folder design as well, not just individual files. We need to add the entire project and directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've listed quite a few problems here. In general I start a new solution like this: 1) Find a `.gitingore` for a VS solution. 2) Make a new empty repository and check-in + commit the `.gitignore`. Do this before... 3) Create and add solution/project files.

Comment: We actually already had/have a `.gitignore` file, for our project.

Comment: Was the `.gitignore` added or modified before the project files were added. You'd also need to check the proper files are ignored or included. Also, before commits I always make it a point to save the solution because that often is omitted leaving the project out of sync when I commit. At this point this is all speculation -- Add some details so someone can actually duplicate the problem and provide concrete answers.